# Emacs: highlight region in inactive window?

Tags: emacs, elisp

Is it possible have an active region highlighted, although its window is
inactive? I'm debugging a region-manipulating function, having code in
one window, and the active region in another.  I need to be in the
code window to eval, but in the other window to see the region, so
currently I have to switch windows each time I update the region.

I've just made a small work-around using [`hlt-highlight-region`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HighlightLibrary), but
it's not perfect and I wonder if there's a default way of doing this.

Comment: Maybe option `highlight-nonselected-windows` will help you here. Dunno.

Comment: @Drew, thanks a lot, that's exactly what I was looking for. Please post as answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try option `highlight-nonselected-windows` -- perhaps it will help you here.